# Odd behaviour of Slick element index

Tags: mootools

I can't manage to put content within the second `p` of this page:

```
<body>
  <p>First: <code></code></p>
  <p>Second: <code></code></p>
</body>
```

I'm using this code

```
var d, firstp, secondp;
d = new Date();
firstp  = $$('p:index(0)');
secondp = $$('p:index(1)'); 
firstp.set('text', d);
secondp.set('text', d); // not changing the dom
```

I know I could do

```
paragraphs = $$('p');
firstp = paragraphs[0];
secondp = paragraphs[1];
```

But why using the Slick selector returns no value?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug... you can use this in the meantime: https://jsfiddle.net/L38oLjry/1/

Comment: You can use `:nth-child()` (first child is 1, not 0)